# wiredesignz modular extensions extending controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am using WireDesignz modular extensions with great success so far. I now have the need to extend a controller within the module. I have created the new controller and the original, now extended, controller and they work fine outside of the HMVC but when I put them inside the module folder and call the new controller it days is can't find the controller it's extending... even though it's right there in the same directory. If I call the original one it's all fine. I'm not sure where to go with this as I can't find anyone with the same problem online. Any ideas? Here's a bit more:

Original controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Calendar extends MY_Controller {...
```

New controller, in same directory:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Calendar_new extends Calendar {...
```

Results in:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Calendar' not found in /home/d/e/demo/web/public_html/application/modules/calendar/controllers/calendar_new.php on line 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base controller class which you are extending is not being included as a resource. Codeigniter will not automatically try to load base classes.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
include('Calendar.php');
class Calendar_new extends Calendar {...
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew it had to be straight forward, but if you don't know then knowing it must be straight forward doesn't help!